# How to prevent text or script file to be seen/download by directly entering it browser url bar?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I am using some java-script code in my JSP file but as I do not want client to see my code, I placed it in a `codescript.js` file and included it through ajax like this

```
$.ajax({
   cache: true,
   dataType: "script",
   url: "codescript.js"
});
```

But as I am accessing codescript.js file directly anyone can guess that it is stored in current directory. My file can be downloaded by just entering file name in url bar such as

```
pathtomysite\codescript.js
```

Is there any way to prevent clients to easily access my java-script files.

Comment: No you can't, the only thing you can do is to obfuscate the code so it's harder to read.

Comment: Is there no way other to prevent some file types to be accessed directly?

Comment: If that file can access via an ajax request, then anyone can see it via DevTools. The only way to protect that file is obfuscate like @jcubic comment.

Comment: Regardless of what you do, I can always install a tool like Fiddler and see all your code. If you want the code to be invisible to the client, don't use a client-side language like JavaScript. Use only server-side technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deny direct access by testing the `Referer` header. This should basically deny direct access, but it can be spoofed.

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" "!www.example.com" [NC]
RewriteRule "\.(js)$" -   [F]
```